# Apache redirecting HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, centos, virtualhost

I have CentOs 7 with Apache. Got virtual hosts there with my website. That is working fine.

But i wanted to install lets encrypt certificate installation went fine, but when i wana load website on https it redirects me back to http and i really dont know why. I didnt found anywhere any redirection rules or something like that.

This are my virtual hosts in etc/httpd/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.hodnoceniopvvv.cz
ServerAlias hodnoceniopvvv.cz
DocumentRoot /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/limesurvey
ErrorLog /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/requests.log combined
```

hodnoceniopvvv.cz-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.hodnoceniopvvv.cz
    ServerAlias hodnoceniopvvv.cz
    DocumentRoot /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/limesurvey
    ErrorLog /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/requests.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hodnoceniopvvv.cz/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And when i try something like that:

```
Redirect permanent / https://hodnoceniopvvv.cz/
```

Browser writes its in loop.

EDIT//

Found .htaacces in my website folder, maby thats causing problems? But when i delete it, its still the same problem.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # deny access to hidden files and directories except .well-known
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.+ - [F]
</IfModule>

# deny access to hidden files and directories without mod_rewrite
RedirectMatch 403 ^/(?!\.well-known/)(.*/)?\.+

# General setting to properly handle LimeSurvey paths
# AcceptPathInfo on
```

Can anybody help or say where should i look for problems?

Thank you,

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing

```
Redirect permanent / https://hodnoceniopvvv.cz
```

in the ssl config file too then it would result in a loop. You only need to redirect it in the file where virtual hosts for port 80 are created i.e. the first config file.

Else

I would suggest you to create two different files for virtual hosts on port 80 and 443 and redirect requests from apache2.conf to these files. The flow would be much clear and more easier to debug further

Comment: i wrote it only in virtual host, and i have 2 different virtual host files it just doesnt look like it from that post.

And its redirecting from https to http without even that redirect and i dont why.

Comment: Did you use a <base href=url /> in there somewhere, probably in index.html. Using this could cause the redirection.